# How to load specific CSV column to the left in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, csv

**My CSV file:**

```
Product Code,Product Description,Net Weight,POR Number,BBE Info (DD/MM/YY)
0001450,Californian Whole Almonds,22.68kg,POR17195,21/11/19
```

**Excel file, when importing the CSV file.**

[image: csv]

**Question**

I'd like to place the `POR Number` column to the left of `Product Code`. But when I refresh the data, it goes back to it's original place.

How can I load the CSV file into excel and choose which column loads up where? Without adjusting the CSV structure.

Here is a desired output when I refresh the CSV data:

[image]

Comment: Import the file by reading the contents in vba and output it the way you want. Then use Application.OnTime to run the code every 1 minute.

Comment: @Andreas just doing some research on that now. Not very familiar with VBA, got any suggested readings for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line and use split to split the columns and then output the data where you need.
Use application.OnTime to run the code every minute.

Make `NextRun` a global date variable

```
sub split_csv()
    File = FreeFile()
    Open "csv.csv" For Input As #File

    i = 2
    While Not EOF(File)
        Line Input #File, csvLine 
        cols = split(csvLine, ",")
        range("A" & i).value = cols(1) ' and so on...

        i = i+1
    Wend

    NextRun = Now + timevalue("00:01:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextRun, Procedure:="split_csv", Schedule:=True
end sub
```

To stop the code from running you have to use `Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=NextRun, Procedure:="split_csv", Schedule:=False`, I'll advice you to add that to workbook_close or if you forget to turn off the function it will open the workbook again and keep going.

Comment: Where? What is out of range?

Comment: Works now.. just closed it and re-opened it

Answer (score 0):

you can use the integrated feature [Get & Transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-Transform-in-Excel-2016-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) (Excel 2016) or earlier Version with the [MS Power Query Add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=39379).

1. Go to Data > New Query > From File > From CSV
2. Select your csv file.  Click Import.
   A preview of the csv data will be shown. Click Edit.
3. Go to Home > Transform > Use First Row As Headers
4. Move the column you want with drog & drap over the column header
5. you may remove some columns with right click on the column header

Give it a try. The UI is very intuitive and you don't have to write any code for most transforming tasks.